# git submodule update --remote does not work

Tags: git, git-submodules

I cloned a git repository, `mainrepo`, which has a submodule `submodule1`. When I try to get the latest update from `submodule1`:

```
$ cd mainrepo

$ git submodule add git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/submodule1.git

$ git submodule update --remote submodule1
Usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b branch] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [-N|--no-fetch] [--rebase] [--reference <repository>] [--merge] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--] [<path>...]

$ git submodule update --remote
Usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b branch] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [-N|--no-fetch] [--rebase] [--reference <repository>] [--merge] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--] [<path>...]
```

I am sure I once tried updating a `submodules` this way, the docs says to do so too, yet I do not understand why it does not work.

But if I do a fetch and merge directly in the `submodule`, it gets updated to the latest repository commit as I want it:

```
$ cd submodule1

$ git fetch && git merge master
```

Why doesn't the `submodule update --remote submodule1` command work?

Maybe that might help:

```
$ vim mainrepo/.git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/mainrepo.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "local/src/utils"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/submodule1.git

$ vim .gitmodules
[submodule "submodule1"]
        path = submodule1
        url = git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/submodule1.git
```

Comment: What version of git (`git --version`)?

Comment: crap git version on that computer is 1.7.1 ... Updating the remote submodules works on my personal computer, which git version is updated to 2.9.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend reading this crash course on Submodules from git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

My guess is that, since the repository you cloned already has a submodule (check for `.gitmodules` in the repo's root!) you shouldn't have to `git submodule add` it again.

Cloning the repository and then running `git submodule update --recursive` should suffice!

Alternatively, `git clone --recurse-submodules` does this automatically for you.

Comment: `git clone --recurse-submodules` fixed it. typically "submodule update recursive" should work, but for some reason wasn't. Any clue on the later?

Answer (score 0):

From the crash course on submodules, this solved the issue for me

```
$git submodule init 
$git submodule update
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case that `git clone --recurse-submodules [git_url]` didn't work and only cloned whole of [git_url] instead of creating submodule, I used `git submodule update --init --recursive` and it created a [submodule_name] folder with that repository content in my project.
[This page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try this cmd

> git rm --cached [dir_path]

to clean local cache, then get the submodules again

> git submodule add git@repository.git [dir_path]